# mesos configuration error in centos7

Tags: python, centos7, mesos

I am trying to install mesos 1.0.1 on centos 7 but i am running into _FORTIFY_SOURCE error.  Has anyone found a fix/workaround? It seems there is a patch but i don't know where to get it from. I'd appreciate any help with this. Thanks!

```
checking whether we can build usable Python eggs... In file included from /usr/include/limits.h:26:0,
    from /usr/local/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/5.3.0/include-fixed/limits.h:168,
    from /usr/local/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/5.3.0/include-fixed/syslimits.h:7,
    from /usr/local/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/5.3.0/include-fixed/limits.h:34,
    from /usr/include/python2.7/Python.h:19,
    from testpyegg.cpp:1:

/usr/include/features.h:330:4: warning: #warning _FORTIFY_SOURCE requires compiling with optimization (-O) [-Wcpp]
warning _FORTIFY_SOURCE requires compiling with optimization (-O)
configure: error: no
```

Answer (score -1):

Adarsh, seems like your error comes from building the Python eggs. Could you paste the full error log, so that we can better help you to triage your issue. BTW, installing Mesos is straight forward. You are not expected to handle issues with `_FORTIFY_SOURCE` or `optimization`. Please follow this document to install Mesos on CentOS.
http://mesos.apache.org/gettingstarted/

BTW, if you have any further question about Mesos, feel free to ask through Mesos mailing list: http://mesos.apache.org/community/
or Mesos slack channel: mesos-slackin.herokuapp.com/

You will get more quick answers from the Mesos community there.

Gilbert